# What happened in StackExchange Mathematics

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

During the last 24 hours, an avalanche of users were asking constantly about basic StackExchange features, Mathematics questions ceased appearing in my news feeds, and I am receiving updates about people finding inconvenience using StackExchange and others whose threads were closed under unjustified cases? Certain specific users (I won't mention the names, I worry this should bother them) are rushing onto StackExchange in a seemingly angry manner. May I have an explanation?

EDIT: those are the screenshots requested by some of you:
[image]
[image]
[image]
The last actual math question was on Oct 24???
and a certain @Martin Sleziak's posts are being displayed constantly on my news feed, I don't know if this is another feed selection error, or maybe actually there is something wrong

Comment: I, personally, haven't noticed anything at all out of the ordinary in Math Stack Exchange.  Can you provide any details or examples of what you are seeing?

Comment: Got a screenshot?

Comment: You appear to be looking at the meta site, not the [math site](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions).  The math site continues to receive math questions in the ordinary way.  Math questions are not meant to appear on the meta site; those that do are swiftly closed.

Comment: Ouh , feels like I am the one with zero experience

Comment: I upvoted this because the interfaces for math.se and math.meta.se are incredibly similar and I think this mistake is very easy to make. And also because "Certain specific users ... are rushing onto StackExchange in a seemingly angry manner" is an excellent description of meta. Welcome, MyDoom. You gave me a good smile this morning.

Comment: This might be useful to notice both on main and on meta: You can use several tabs: such as Newest, Active, Bountied, Unanswered, Frequent. Depending on the choice of tab, you're shown different question. If you choose newest, the name of the user which is displayed is the poster of the question. If you choose active, you're shown the name of the user responsible for the most recent activity - which might be editor, answerer, etc. So, as you can easily check, the claim about Martin Sleziak's posts is simply not true. (Sorry if I commented in seemingly angry manner.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak- Oh, I hope it didn't sound like I was making veiled reference to you, although reading the screenshot more carefully I could understand why it would look that way. I've been following meta for about a year now, so that comment made me think about the number of times I've seen people come charging into meta with a full head of steam. (cont'd ...)

Comment: (...cont'd) I've learned to pay attention to the "posted/modified/answered" verb in the annotation, and honestly the people who show up with "modified/answered" (which includes you) tend to be folks who made a mature and calm response to the post, as opposed to those who just made snarky comments, which doesn't show up on the front tabs, and, honestly, tends to include me.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I commented mainly because I was explicitly named in the post (although misspelled). I will certainly admit that I am here on meta more than it's healthy. (I am trying my best to reduce that.) Still, if I see something which, in my opinion, needs editing, then I do edit - so I am not surprised that my name pops up a lot in those screenshots. Mainly with the word "modified" next to it. Anyway, +1 for me - for providing the screenshots after they were request in the comments.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: D'oh, I really need to learn to read all the way to the end of a post before commenting! I only read to the point where I figured out what had happened to MyDoom, had an honestly out-loud laugh, and scrolled down to comment. I hadn't noticed your explicit naming. If it's of any value I don't see you as editing too much or commenting poorly, and I'm in the same boat as you in realizing that I should spend less time in meta but don't seem to be able to cut back.

Comment: @Martin the time you spend here on meta is valued & appreciated by me and, I'm sure, by many, many of those who come here regularly.

Comment: For any new users, in Maths Meta SE, you have the same reputation as the main site, but badges are earned separately given your stats on the *meta* site. Meta SE which is the meta site for *all* SE sites does not bring over your reputation from any other site, and badges are the same.

Comment: Although this question has a score of $0$, it currently stands at +5/-5 for any users who cannot see the vote totals.

Comment: There is more information about what the meta site is for [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta). One more point: voting expresses agreement/disagreement and not question/answer quality, so you do not gain or lose reputation for posts (but you do gain badges).